# How to use where for nested relationship in laravel controller

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, controller, left-join

How to use where for nested relationship in laravel controller.

```
Product::with('productstore.entitystore.entity')
->where('account_id',$account_id)->get();
```

**product** table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple |
| 2 | Orange |

**products_store** table (one product has many store)

| id | product_id | store_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |

**store** table (one store has one entity / one entity has multiple store)

| id | entity_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |

**entity** table (One entity has one account / one account has multiple entity)

| id | account_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |

In Product Model

```
public function productstore()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ProductStore','product_id');
}
```

In ProductStore Model

```
public function entitystore()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Store','id');
}
```

In Store Model

```
public function entity()
{
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Entity','entity_id','id');
}
```

Here I am getting error for **account_id**

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'account_id' in 'where clause'
```

Can some one suggest to solve this and is the way of relationship am using is correct.

Comment: is the code you shared not working?

Comment: @apokryfos working, but cant able to get the correct data in with

Comment: In these cases it's more helpful if you provide sample data, expected result and actual result otherwise we can't guess what it is your are asking about

Comment: Do you have a working query in mysql? If not, then I would recommend starting there ;)

Comment: @apokryfos I have edited my question. Can you pls check my edits.

Comment: @Techno I can able to do it with SQL query in phpMyAdmin but in laravel model i'm trying. Can you pls check my edits.

Comment: So to be clear, you want to load all `products` that have a linked `entity` with `account_id` `$account_id`?

Comment: yes. I am trying to get the products with dynamic **$account_id**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is to load all products containing a link to entities with `account_id = $account_id`, you need something like [this](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```
$products = Product
    ::with([
        'productstore.entitystore.entity' => function($query) use($account_id) {
            $query->where('account_id', $account_id);
        }
    ])
    ->whereHas('productstore.entitystore.entity', function($query) use($account_id) {
        $query->where('account_id', $account_id);
    })
    ->get();
```

`whereHas` accepts the name of the relationship(link) as first argument, and a callback function in the second argument. It will now only load the products that have an entity with an account_id you provided.

You can see that I'm also performing the same query in `with` to ensure you only have the valid entities loaded with the products that come up.

Comment: @BoopathiD np ;)